# Convert Scientific Notation into decimal number using bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I need to convert 1.22661727081984E+002 to 122.661727081984 using shell script. I have tried it using the below command:

```
echo "+1.22661727081984E+002" | awk -F"E" 'BEGIN{OFMT="%10.10f"} {print $1 * (10 ^ $2)}'
```

output:

```
122.6617270820
```

It is giving me the output but rounding off the last 4 digits.

I need the output without rounding off the result.

Comment: @jww I have updated my question. Can you please check now ?

Comment: Why are you using `OFMT="%10.10f"` if you don't want the rounding of the 4 least significant digits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Bash's `printf`:

```
$ printf "%.14f\n" 1.22661727081984E+002
122.66172708198400
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk` you can do it on this way:

```
awk '{ printf("%.100f\n",$1) }'
```

(assuming the number is first parameter)

Example:

```
echo "+1.22661727081984E+002"|awk '{ printf("%.100f\n",$1) }'
122.6617270819839973228226881474256515502930000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

(you can limit the number of digits by change the number in front of `f`)